# Adding classes to subchildren with addClass

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I am trying to add the class 'animated fadeInDown" to the subchildren of h1, so that the letters individually fade in from the top instead of all doing it at once. The reason I cannot just type these classes in by hand is because I am using lettering.js, which breaks up "lorem ips" into its constituents when the doc loads.

```
<h1 id = "letters">
  <span class="char1">l</span>
  <span class="char2">o</span>
  <span class="char3">r</span>
  <span class="char4">e</span>
  <span class="char5">m</span>
  <span class="char6"> </span>
  <span class="char7">i</span>
  <span class="char8">p</span>
  <span class="char9">s</span>
</h1>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letters").children().addClass('animated fadeInDown');
});
```

In fact, ideally, I would only like the first 5 to have that class applied rather than on all of them.

Comment: you add the will on settimeout or just add them?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/na4g1jg2/) check the demo first 5 has only the class

Answer (score 5):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letters").find('span:lt(5)').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
});
```

```css
.animated{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id = "letters">
  <span class="char1">l</span>
  <span class="char2">o</span>
  <span class="char3">r</span>
  <span class="char4">e</span>
  <span class="char5">m</span>
  <span class="char6"> </span>
  <span class="char7">i</span>
  <span class="char8">p</span>
  <span class="char9">s</span>
</h1>
```

1. use [:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set

Comment: This is the best answer, I think using a selector is better then cycling through the elements.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var time = 500;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letters").children().each(function(i) {
    if (i <5) {
    $(this).delay(time).queue(function() { $(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown').dequeue(); });
    time += 500;
      }
    i++;
  });
});
```

```css
.animated {
  font-size:50px;
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="letters">
      <span class="char1">l</span>
      <span class="char2">o</span>
      <span class="char3">r</span>
      <span class="char4">e</span>
      <span class="char5">m</span>
      <span class="char6"> </span>
      <span class="char7">i</span>
      <span class="char8">p</span>
      <span class="char9">s</span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: @LXXIII it doesn't appear to be working, when I checked the chrome dev tools, the class wasnt appended either.

Comment: @LXXIII You can also do this by doing `delay(500*i)`, note the OP wants to only do this with the first 5 items.

Comment: @LXXIII Looks good, although you don't necessarily need the count, the first parameter in `.each(function(i)` counts as a index.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Edited!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()` and add a condition based on the index of the elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letters").children().each(function(i){
    if( i < 5 ) $(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
  })
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bq42pnks/)

You can also do this with the `lt` selector, as @guradio showed in their comment:

```
$("#letters").find('span:lt(5)').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
```

Comment: @Spencer_Wieczorek it doesn't appear to be working, when I checked the chrome dev tools, the class wasnt appended either.

Comment: @WillAshley It works fine in the fiddle, I don't see any problems with the code I gave.

Answer (score 0):

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/1sbgkdgw/) hightlighting in red, the first 5 childrens of `letters`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#letters").children().first().addClass('animated fadeInDown').nextUntil(".char6").addClass('animated fadeInDown');
});
```